# Not able to post comments or give votes on my question

Tags: support

Can somebody tell me what is happening with my account? I am not able to post comments or give votes on my question.

Like if others are posting comments on my question, I am not able to open the 'Add Comment' block below those comments.

So, please tell me wat are the solution..

Comment: Which question(s) are you unable to comment etc? What **exactly** happens?

Comment: You aren't supposed to be able to vote for (rate) your own questions.

Comment: How on Earth someone can be able to rate his own question/answer?

Comment: This type of question belongs on meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: On StackOverflow you are rated by the community. You cannot rate your own questions. And questions like this one will be negatively rated.

Comment: Shivi, did you indeed mean "comment" when you [originally wrote "reply"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/73310/revisions)? Please use the "edit" link underneath your questions explain some more!

Comment: PLEASE, more details. Were you indeed trying to vote on your own questions, or on posts that answered your questions? Which questions are giving the problems?

Comment: Your last edit is, again, NOT helpful at all, Shivi. People here *are* trying to help, but you just do not give us the information we ask for. :-( So, PLEASE, again: Which question(s) are you unable to comment etc? What **exactly** happens? Were you indeed trying to vote on your own questions, or on posts that answered your questions? Which questions are giving the problems? Does clicking your own user name in the top header indeed show you http://stackoverflow.com/users/397868/shivi? And is the question you're having problems with, shown on that page?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me you're not logged in, or logged in using another account.

User names are not unique. So if you created multiple accounts *and* if the reputation of the second account [is below 50](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), then you can only use the original account to comment on your own questions. Also, you need at least 15 reputation to vote up posts from other users.

So: does clicking your own user name in the top header indeed show you https://stackoverflow.com/users/397868/shivi? And is the question you're having problems with, shown on that page?